# Python - pyinstaller. Проблема при сборке

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

ОС - debian 10. При попытке собрать проект pyinstaller'ом (собираю из под venv'a) возникает такая ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Команды которые предлагает, я конечно же пробовал, после этого ошибка такая же.
Питон собирал сам через такие команды:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j 2
sudo make altinstall
```

(так же пробовал с флагом --enabled-shared)

UPDATE:

libpython3.8.a есть в папке где я конфигурирую питон

Comment: [PyInstaller не гарантирует сборку в pyenv](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4643#issuecomment-586405653)

Comment: А сам PyInstaller где установлен? в venv или в основной системе? Чтобы избежать ряда глюков pyinstaller должен быть там же где и Ваш код.

Comment: @Kers  В venv'е.